# Rails 3 Uploadify + Paperclip File Data Is Never Sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, uploadify

I'm using Rails 3.1 with Paperclip and trying to implement Uploadify for multiple file uploads on a single page. I tried following various samples, including: [Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify](https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify)

Currently I have a Upload model which has a one to many relationship with my UploadImage model - This is what I had setup so far for my view:

UploadImages/new.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "swfobject.js", "jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.js" %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    <%- session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] -%> 
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // Create an empty object to store our custom script data
        var uploadify_script_data = {};

        // Fetch the CSRF meta tag data
        var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
        var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');

        // Now associate the data in the config, encoding the data safely
        uploadify_script_data[csrf_token] = encodeURI(encodeURI(csrf_param));

        $('.uploadify').uploadify
        ({
            uploader        :   '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            cancelImg       :   '/uploadify/cancel.png',
            multi           :   true,
            auto            :   false,
            onComplete      :   function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data)
                                { 
                                    var dat = eval('(' + response + ')');
                                    $.getScript(dat.upload);
                                },
            scriptData      :   {
                                    '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
                                    'format' : 'json',
                                    '_method': 'post',
                                    '<%= session_key %>' : encodeURIComponent('<%= u cookies[session_key] %>'),
                                    'authenticity_token': encodeURIComponent('<%= u form_authenticity_token %>'),
                                    'upload_id' : '<%= @upload.id %>'
                                }
        });         
    }); 


</script>

<%= form_for @upload.upload_images.build, :html => { :class => "upload", :multipart => true } do |f| %>  
                    <%= f.file_field :image, :class => "uploadify" %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Submit Upload", :disable_with => "Uploading", :class => "submit"%>
<% end %>
```

I see the uploadify flash button, I select a few files and submit but this is all I see in my params:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"K1bSH/FO0Hjdum0aiNU45mHJXezXTiCgh9XVmk1jrZM=",
>   "commit"=>"Submit Upload", "action"=>"create",
>   "controller"=>"upload_images"}

As you can see there is no file data being sent and even the scriptData that I specify doesn't get sent, I noticed that other people's code uses the **script** parameter for the uploadify function. In PHP frameworks they point it to the .php file which handles the saving. I'm using Paperclip so I wasn't sure how to implement this... perhaps this is my problem? Let me know if you need any additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at this question: [uploadify rails 3 nothing happens after the file is chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276315/uploadify-rails-3-0-nothing-happens-after-file-is-chosen?rq=1)

I had to attach some events to my submit button and add the script parameter to the uploadify function as I surmised.

So for starters in my config/routes.rb I needed to add:

```
post "upload_images/create"
```

And in my view I added:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });


$('#submit').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.uploadify').uploadifyUpload();
});
```

and finally I added the script param to my initial uploadify function call:

```
script          :   '/upload_images/create'
```

After many hours of beating my head against it's finally working and making sense! Hope this helps somebody else.